# access pointer to function in unmanaged code

Tags: c++, c, c++-cli, clr

I am creating a CLR project to access my C code.  It was going ok till one of the C function needed a callback.  I'm not sure how to resolve this, have tried a couple of different things.

C:

```
typedef void(*logger_callback_t)(const char *, int);
```

Given the above in C, how can I assign this callback?  I've tried creating a function and referencing it but getting errors.  If I put the c++ function in the header it gives "pointer-to-member is not valid for a managed class".  If I put it next to the function I get undeclared identifier

C++:

```
logger_callback_t logger = &dummy_logger_callback;

void dummy_logger_callback(const char *, int)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not super clear on the issue but it seems like this is a declaration order problem. One option may be to forward declare the callback until the function is declared.

```
static logger_callback_t logger;

static void dummy_logger_callback(const char *, int)
{
}

logger = dummy_logger_callback;
```

This should work in a C context, but if your function is a method of a class or your variable is a member of a class this can get more complex. It is also complicated by what the intended storage class (`static`, `extern` etc) is for the variable and the function. Could you be more specific about the setup?

Comment: Ok, so the setup is a C library that contains functions I need to do something and get back results.  One of the parameters to be passed into the C function is one of these function pointers.  For example:      doSomething(double a, logger_callback_t logger).  I'm setting up a CLR project as like a middle man that can be used from C# that takes the data from C#, creates the necessary structures and then calls the C code and returns the results to C#.  Everything else is working except for those functions that take one of these as a parameter.

Comment: If that is the case you should be able to use the code I've posted, in a source file declaring everything as static outside of a class.

Answer (score 0):

That callback should be a free function, not a member function. If you're declaring it inside a class, don't.

Valid code might look like:

```
// at file scope (not inside a class):
extern "C" {
  void dummy_logger_callback(const char *, int)
  {
    // your code here
  }
}

  // ... and in your existing C++ code:
  logger_callback_t logger = &dummy_logger_callback;
```